Quartz's CronTrigger for every 8 hours fails - java
I have setup cron expression, to run job at every 8 hours
trigger.setCronExpression("0 0/480 * * * ?");

but this is not working fine. job runs every after 1 hour.
Java / Quartz Scheduler
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
   trigger.setName("data-checks-job");
   trigger.setStartTime(CommonUtil.getBeforeTimeInHour("1", "yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss"));
   trigger.setCronExpression("0 0/480 * * * ?"); 


0 0 0/8 ? * * * every 8 hours.

Your expression is not valid.
You can't exceed the 24 on the hours section:
Hours:
"0/8" means every 8 hours starting at hour 0.
Every 8 hours valid Cron Expression:
0 0 0/8 ? * * *

This is working fine

But job starts running couple of hours after deployment.
I want first job to start right after deployment.

You can't achieve that with Cron Expression, You can specify a specific time to begin Ex(* * 3/8 ? * * *) "every 8 hours starting at hour 3". However your all scheduler will be effected by that specific time. What you need to look is how to run jobs "periodically".

Does 3/8 means, the first job will start at 3am?  What about 3pm, should it be like 15/8 ?

Yes. it is 0 0 15/8 ? * * *
